# How to change the folder directory on GitBash

Tags: git, github

I have used gitbash for a little bit of time ever since never had a problem. I am currently working on some project and I need to push ot to my github account. When I open git all I can see is this image. I dont know how to go to the project folder its ignoring when I type "cd .." to go back.

[image: image of git]

Comment: I am trying to push the project folder on to my github repository

Comment: yes its ready All i need is to go into my project folder through git and creat git init

Comment: I know how to push, but I need to go into my project  folder

Comment: Somehow I cant get out of the folder it is now on git

Comment: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
when i try to run git status...

Comment: So how do I go to my project folder ?

Comment: can you help me how can I go back go to my root and change folders. because I need to be in my project folder in order for me to push it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `cd` to navigate to your project.

Let's say that your project was at: `C:/dev/project1`

Then, in your git bash window type:

```
cd /c/dev/project1
```

Once you have traversed to your project correctly you can proceed to run Git commands.